# Is the css :target selector supported in IE9 in spite of w3schools saying it's not?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

The site I have built and which I'm maintaining has divs that are visible depending on whether they are :target or not. Since w3schools has told me (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) that no version of Internet Explorer supports the :target selector, I built a separate IE site.

Now it seems, though, that IE9 *does* correctly display my code. You can find the site [here](http://www.yben.eu). It automatically forwards to the IE site for IE8 and lower now.

Can I safely use this construction for IE9, or should I have IE9 forward to the backup site as well?

Comment: Check this out http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @PraveenKumar That's... good to know. Is there a reference that *is* up-to-date concerning things like these?

Comment: [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) is also nice for detailed information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, IE9 is the first version of Internet Explorer to support the `:target` pseudo-class, so you are safe to use it with IE9

That aside, w3schools is not generally considered to be the best resource for up-to-date information. I find [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/) a cleaner and more comprehensive resource, as shown by the [search result for `:target`](http://caniuse.com/#search=:target).

You will often see people mentioning http://w3fools.com/ which explains why some people think w3schools is a bad resource. I recommend reading this and making your own mind up on continuing to use it. Personally I don't use w3shcools and prefer [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/) and the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Can I Use doesn't reference IE 9. So what to say?

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino click the **Show all** button to see older browsers

Comment: @andyb I supposed by comparing other browsers that have more previous versions listed that the only version 11 was supported. That' is curious why CanIUse has this justice for IE and Edge hiding previous versions and not doing the same justice for other browsers... curious by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Best alternates to use when you wanna check the support of features:

- [HTML5 & CSS3 Support by Find Me By IP](http://fmbip.com/litmus)
- [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/)
- [Sitepoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) *They have the version numbers too!*

Hope this helps. Do not trust W3Schools.